# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell , UITableView Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableViewController` with each `UITableViewCell` containing a `UICollectionView` where contents of `UICollectionView` should be fully visible. My problem is that when returning height of `UITableViewCell` I cannot return the correct height because I cant figure out how to calculate the `contentSize` of a `UICollectionView` for its contents.

Comment: Do you want that http://eithanshavit.com/2015/04/18/Dynamic_Size_UICollectionView_Cell.html

Comment: can you show some code? and why not use a full collectionview instead of adding it to a tableview?

Comment: Code is available in this URL : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bD5h4vCJXcc2hnSWk0TXd1LWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.You need to set estimated height for the tableview as welll if you want dynamic tableview height.

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight
```

You have to make sure that your cells have exactly same height as the collection view.When you setup your cells in the outer tableview try to reload your data in the inner collectionview otherwise due to reusable cell logic API will not distinguish between previous collection view.

Updated:

I had a case where I had to store a tableview inside a cell.

The inner cell looks like this where the tableview is stored.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var uploadedDocumentsTableView: UITableView! // has 0 to left right top botton margin to superview on storyboard prototype (Contenview)
   @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCellHeight: NSLayoutConstraint! //To constraint the height of the tableview inside the cell.


  //This function is called when the outer tableview delegate calls cellForRowAtIndexPath to deque a cell.
   override func setupWithCellModel(cellModel: CRCustomerAreaDetailsCellModel)   {

    let castedCellModel = cellModel as? CRCustomerAreaDocumentUploadCellModel
    if  let documents = castedCellModel?.docUploadItem?.documents {
        tableViewCellHeight.constant = CGFloat(documents.count * 60)
    }   
    uploadedDocumentsTableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Ordinary

```
extension CRCustomerAreaDocumentUploadV2GalleryCell: UITableViewDataSource {

public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let castedCellModel = cellModel as? CRCustomerAreaDocumentUploadCellModel
    if  let documents = castedCellModel?.docUploadItem?.documents {
        return documents.count
    }
    return 0
}

public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
   //Return your cell
}
```

}

My outer tableview's height is calculated by automatic dimension but for the inner tableview i need to specify the height by myself.

Comment: I have already done this..this works fine in other cases...but in the case of a UICollectionVIew inside a UITableviewCell...this does not work as expected...

Comment: UIScrollView does not have correct intrinsic content size.

Comment: yes sure but you can store it in a property if all the collection view rows have the same height. (numberOfrows*rowheight)

Comment: Sorry, can you extend your comment, I don't understand what exactly are you meaning. How can you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension if cells in the collection view have same height?

Comment: In both examples you exactly (explicitly) set height of cells. (In the outer cell you use tableViewCellHeight constraint, you can replace this code to heightForRow.... . HeightForRow will more quick than autolayout).

Comment: unfortunately i can't because there are also other types of cells (6 different) in my outer tableview

Comment: O, I know about that problem %). This is problem of the instruments (SDK). Create a table view with many kinds of different cells with complicated logic of visibility is very difficult. I've implemented my private tool to avoid this problem.  Look at https://cocoapods.org/pods/DTTableViewManager or https://cocoapods.org/pods/RETableViewManager these solutions are very similar to my solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have read so many times about this. You shouldn't put CollectionView inside TableViewCell. It may cause lots of troubles (e.g. frame drops). Have you tried using StackView instead? Have you tried AsyncDiplayKit?

Comment: My requirement is that I have a vertical dynamic scrollable page with dynamic horizontal scrollable items...any other ideas to do it....UIStackView won't help in this case

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to determine cell's size with UICollectionView inside, because a collection view does not have a correct intrinsic content size. You should overload the [height](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc) method of UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And return correct height from this method.

Another method is create custom view that contains UICollectionView and controls content of the collection view (example from my code):

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height);

    return size;
}

- (void)addTags:(NSArray<BLTag*>*)tags
{
    [_tagsList addObjectsFromArray:tags];

    [self _reloadData];
}
```

This view returns correct intrinsic content size therefore you can insert it to a cell with automatic dimension height.